# How to add and show weights on edges of a undirected graph using PyGraphviz?

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphviz, pygraphviz

```
import pygraphviz as pgv
A = pgv.AGraph()
A.add_node('Alice')
A.add_node('Emma')
A.add_node('John')
A.add_edge('Alice', 'Emma')
A.add_edge('Alice', 'John')
A.add_edge('Emma', 'John')
print A.string()
print "Wrote simple.dot"
A.write('simple.dot')  # write to simple.dot
B = pgv.AGraph('simple.dot')  # create a new graph from file
B.layout()  # layout with default (neato)
B.draw('simple.png')  # draw png
print 'Wrote simple.png'
```

I want to add weights to the edges which should also show up on the figure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add attributes to the edges when you create them:

```
A.add_edge('Alice', 'Emma', weight=5)
```

or you can set them later with:

```
edge = A.get_edge('Alice', 'Emma')
edge.attr['weight'] = 5
```

To add textual information to edges, give them a `label` attribute instead:

```
edge = A.get_edge('Alice', 'Emma')
edge.attr['label'] = '5'
```

All attributes are internally stored as strings but GraphViz interprets these as specific types; see the [attribute documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html).

Comment: well, weight changes the length of the edge. But is there a way to show the weights near the edge in the image.

Comment: Give them an explicit label: `edge.attr['label'] = '5'`

Comment: You may want to refer to the GraphViz documentation itself to see [what attributes are supported](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html).