# How to draw loops-edges in networkx indirected Graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have the following graph:

```
graph = {("A","A"): 3, ("A","B"): 4, ("A","C"): 1}
```

And I am trying to draw a graph that shows a loop in node ("A") labeled with the number 3. The loop should look like the one for node (1) [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/6n-graph2.svg).

It has to be an indirected graph.

So far I am using this:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()

for edge in graph:
    G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])
graph_pos=nx.shell_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,graph_pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,graph_pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, graph_pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, graph_pos, edge_labels = graph)

plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image]

As you can see, there is no loop around node "A" even thought there is an edge ("A", "A"). Any idea on how I can make it happen?

**EDIT - why not a duplicate?**

The question [Matplotlib and Networkx - drawing a self loop node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340520/matplotlib-and-networkx-drawing-a-self-loop-node) is for directed graphs. When you create a graph using `G=nx.MultiDiGraph` you can set attributes for the edges using `G.graph['edge']`.

Using `nx.Graph()` (indirected graph), the results for `G.graph['edge']` is an empty dictionary.

The difference between that question and this question is, in essence, that I use `nx.Graph` and that question uses `nx.MultiDiGraph`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib and Networkx - drawing a self loop node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340520/matplotlib-and-networkx-drawing-a-self-loop-node)

Comment: Please delete this comment. That is the answer for `nx.MultiDiGraph`, meaning a direct graph. I need an indirected graph. When you create a `G = nx.Graph()`, there is no such thing as `G.graph['edge']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P.E. Normand's answer made me take a look at `graphviz` and I realised that, if I change the `arrowsize` of a directed graph to 0, it looks like an indirected graph. Using that I could reuse the answer in [Matplotlib and Networkx - drawing a self loop node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340520/matplotlib-and-networkx-drawing-a-self-loop-node), but I still lacked the label edges. Using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455855/how-to-add-and-show-weights-on-edges-of-a-undirected-graph-using-pygraphviz) I managed to create the following graph:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import to_agraph

graph = {("A","A"): 3, ("A","B"): 4, ("A","C"): 1}
G=nx.MultiDiGraph()

# add edges
for edge in graph:
    G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])

# arrow size: '0' makes it look like an indirected graph
G.graph['edge'] = {'arrowsize': '0', 'splines': 'curved'}
G.graph['graph'] = {'scale': '3'}

A = to_agraph(G)
A.layout('dot')

# set edge labels
for pair in graph:
    edge = A.get_edge(pair[0], pair[1])
    edge.attr['label'] = str(graph[pair]) + "  "

A.draw('test.png')
```

Here is the graph:

[image]

This answer could be a duplicate of the question for directed graphs, I still believe it's worth it to keep with the small tweak for indirected graphs.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, the draw functions of networkx do not make any effort drawing self loops.
The thing that make me say that is: if you change your script to

```
    import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G=nx.Graph()
graph = {("A","A"): 3, ("A","B"): 4, ("A","C"): 1}
#graph = {("A","B"): 4, ("A","C"): 1}
for edge in graph:
    G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1])
graph_pos=nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, graph_pos, edge_labels = graph)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,graph_pos, alpha=0.1)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,graph_pos)
#nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, graph_pos)


plt.show()
```

[image]

you will notice that the edge label is shown. In Networkx it seems that the edges are just lines between vertex. A line between the same point is well… nothing…

So I think you will have no luck with networkx.

However using pygraphviz is your best bet as suggested in [Matplotlib and Networkx - drawing a self loop node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340520/matplotlib-and-networkx-drawing-a-self-loop-node)

From my knowledge [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) (warning it comes only in 32 bits) (and it's python wrapper pygraphviz which needs graphviz) is still a very good graph visualizer.

After installation you can use the to_agraph function of networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.

Good luck.